# Basisness of $|\sin(nx)|$ in $L^2(0, \pi/2)$

Tags: fourier-series, approximation-theory, schauder-basis

The basisness of $\sin(nx)$ in $L^2(0,\pi)$ is a very classical fact.

I wonder whether the system of absolute values $|\sin(nx)|$ is also a basis (or, at least, a complete system) in $L^2(0,\pi)$.
Clearly, every $|\sin(nx)|$ is an even function with respect to $x=\pi/2$. In particular, such functions cannot approximate a noneven function, and, consequently, the restriction to half-interval $(0,\pi/2)$ is necessary.

Thus, my precise question can be formulated as follows.

> Do the functions $|\sin(nx)|$ form a basis (or, at least, a complete system) in $L^2(0,\pi/2)$?

Perhaps, the answer to this simply-stated question is well known, but I was not able to find it in the literature. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true?

Comment: @DionelJaime Honestly, I have no idea what is the correct answer. For me, this question is of pure curiosity. But it somewhat naturally appears in the study of basisness of a sequence of certain parameter-dependent functions, whose limits (wrt the parameter) are $|\sin(nx)|$.